# How to "match" complex patterns like tables with Geb Page?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, automated-tests, spock, geb

Suppose I have complex construct with repeating patterns like a long table with data or like nesting constructs.

Just a small example:

```
<div id="mycontroller1">

    <div class="myfield1">Some text11</div>
    <div class="myfield2">Some text12</div>

</div>

<div id="mycontroller2">

    <div class="myfield1">Some text21</div>
    <div class="myfield2">Some text22</div>

</div>
```

and suppose the content of these divs can be changed by javascript and I wish to check it. I would like to write something like:

```
def 'Whether my page worked correctly'() {

    when:
        to MyPage
        ...

    then:

        assert mycontroller1.myfield1 == "Some text11"
        assert mycontroller1.myfield2 == "Some text12"

        assert mycontroller2.myfield1 == "Some text21"
        assert mycontroller2.myfield2 == "Some text22"

}
```

i.e. access fields via intermediate hierarchy member (note dot notation).

How would I write Page definition then?

Currently I suspect I know how to write "flat" way

```
class MyPage extends Page {

    static url ...

    static at ...

    static content = {

        mycontroller1_myfield1 {
            $('#mycontroller1 .myfield1').text()
        }

        mycontroller1_myfield2 {
            $('#mycontroller1 .myfield2').text()
        }

        mycontroller2_myfield1 {
            $('#mycontroller2 .myfield1').text()
        }

        mycontroller2_myfield2 {
            $('#mycontroller2 .myfield2').text()
        }



    }

}
```

which allow to test "flat" (note underscore)

```
def 'Whether my page worked correctly'() {

    when:
        to MyPage
        ...

    then:
        assert mycontroller1_myfield1 == "Some text11"
        assert mycontroller1_myfield2 == "Some text12"

        assert mycontroller2_myfield1 == "Some text21"
        assert mycontroller2_myfield2 == "Some text22"

}
```

How to write hierarchical?

Also, I was required to write search for `$('#mycontroller1` many times, which looks excessive. If I would able to select some block and then add some furhter selections or checks to that block -- this would be great.

Comment: Why not just call them `myfield1` in the `content` block?

Comment: There can be duplicates in some circumstances. For example, many forms on page etc.

Comment: I can rewrite question with classes or with nesting finds if you wish

Comment: Done rewriting with classes so we can avoid sticking on repeating ids question :)

Comment: could be a job for modules http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.12.1/#modules

Answer (score 0):

You should use a class that extends `Module` to model repeating content - repeating across different pages or in a single page. Modules are explained in [this chapter of The Book of Geb](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#modules) and there is even section abut [using modules for repeating content](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#repeating-content).